# Let $1=n_0<n_1<\ldots$ be an increasing sequence of positive integers. True/False: $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{n_{i+1}-n_i}{n_{i+1}}$ diverges to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, problem-solving

Let $1=n_0<n_1<n_2<\ldots$ be an increasing sequence of positive integers. Is it true that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{n_{i+1}-n_i}{n_{i+1}} $ diverges to $+\infty?$

For example, if $n_1=2,n_2=3,n_3=53,n_4=54,$ then the first few terms are $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{50}{53}, \frac{1}{54}.$ Since $\frac{50}{53}<\displaystyle\sum_{k=4}^9 \frac{1}{k},$ this makes me think it might be possible to come up with a counter-exmaple.

Comment: @DavidMitra: I have added another one to the list which answers this question exactly.

Answer (score 4):

The series diverges. Hint: for a fixed $k$ and $\ell$ big enough we have $$\frac{n_{k+1}-n_k}{n_{k+1}}+\frac{n_{k+2}-n_{k+1}}{n_{k+2}}+\ldots+\frac{n_{\ell}-n_{\ell-1}}{n_{\ell}}>\frac{n_{k+1}-n_k}{n_{\ell}}+\frac{n_{k+2}-n_{k+1}}{n_{\ell}}+\ldots+\frac{n_{\ell}-n_{\ell-1}}{n_{\ell}} = \frac{n_\ell-n_k}{n_\ell}\ge \frac 12$$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The key in this answer is that for any $k$ we can find sufficiently large $l>k$ such that the sum from the $(k+1)$-th term to the $l$-th term is larger that $\frac{1}{2}$, thus by Cauchy's convergence criteria the original sum diverges.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy was right though in pointing that it should be written somewhere that $\ell >  k$, but this answer is correct (and the exercise is nice). Also shows that the hypothesis increasing sequence of positive integers can be relaxed (increasing to infinity suffices).

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** I missed the assumption that the sequences has to consist of integers, by bad. Nonetheless I'll leave my answer up regardless as it might still bring some insight to the problem.

Notice first that

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{n_{j+1}-n_j}{n_{j+1}}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{n_j}{n_{j+1}}\right).$$

One can thus immediately see that if

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\frac{n_j}{n_{j+1}}\neq1,$$

then the series diverges, so we have to consider sequences where $\frac{n_j}{n_{j+1}}\to1$ if we wish to find a counterexample. Consider the sequence $\{n_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ given by

$$n_j=\frac{2j}{j+1}.$$

Now clearly this sequence is strictly increasing, and $n_0=1$. For this sequence we have that

$$1-\frac{n_j}{n_{j+1}}=1-\frac{2j}{j+1}\cdot\frac{j+2}{2(j+1)}=1-\frac{(j+1)^2-1}{(j+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(j+1)^2}.$$

This means that

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{n_{j+1}-n_j}{n_{j+1}}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(j+1)^2}=\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{1}{j^2},$$

which clearly converges. So the conclusion you can draw is that if $\frac{n_j}{n_{j+1}}\not\to1$ as $j\to\infty$, then it diverges, but otherwise it is inconclusive.

Comment: The $n_j$ are integers?

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh shit, I missed that assumption by bad.